# Integral $\int\limits_0^\infty \text{d}q \cos(qx) (\omega^2-q^2)^{N-1} e^{-s(\omega^2-q^2)^N}$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

In my research I am interested in finding the following expression:

$$ f{}_\omega^N(x) := \int\limits_0^{\ell^{\,2N}} \text{d}s ~ \mathcal{I}{}_\omega^N(x,s) $$
where the main problem lies in finding an analytic expression for
$$ \mathcal{I}{}_\omega^N(x,s) := \int\limits_0^\infty \frac{\text{d}q}{\pi} \cos(qx) (\omega^2-q^2)^{N-1} e^{-s(\omega^2-q^2)^N} \, , \quad N \ge 2 \, , \quad s > 0 \, , \quad x \in \mathbb{R} \, .$$
For $s>0$ this integral is convergent, and it can be evaluated numerically in principle. However, it would be nice to have an analytic expression.

In the case $N=1$ the result can be specified in terms of the imaginary error function and one obtains
$$ \mathcal{I}^1_\omega(x,s) = \frac{e^{x^2/(4s)-s\,\omega^2}}{4\sqrt{\pi s}}\left[ \text{erfi}\left(\frac{2qs-ix}{2\sqrt{s}}\right) + \text{erfi}\left(\frac{2qs+ix}{2\sqrt{s}}\right) \right] \, ,$$
but in a general case (or even just for $N=2$) I cannot solve the integral. Any ideas?